# How can I handle SCORM integration in web application? Or how can I integrate Moodle player in my webpage

Tags: php, moodle, scorm

I want to implement [SCORM](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/) upload functionality and SCORM package play functionality in my web app which is in php so please suggest any solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Moodle is modular enough to extract what you want out of it directly, but you could learn from how they managed to do it.  It may even be worth upgrading it to your architecture anyway.

- uploading a zip
- expanding on your server
- reading the imsmanifest.xml to make the appropriate Table of contents
- assigning
- launching the content*

*Moodle runs the SCORM 1.2 API literally named "API" which has all the communication methods for the content to communicate data back to the LMS.  You'd have to reverse engineer that as well which means managing the student attempt or CMI object on your server too.  Extensive bit of work, but possible.